# How to know, when I have to use {{- instead of {{ when producing yaml?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Completely new to helm, I cannot understand how this whitespace removal work. I've read that {{- should just remove whitespaces/newlines. I'd expect it to remove from expression within brackets, but I would put my had into mildly warm water that I saw removing white spaces *before* brackets. What does it actually do?

Also, using helm producing yaml(where whitespaces, indentation and newlines are significant characters :| ), single missing/extra dash will produce error.

Is there some recommendation which pattern of dashes to use to avoid issues? Since I really didn't find reliable definition of what is removed I constantly have to test all permutations to find winning combination...

EDIT: **or** how to debug it to know **what** is wrong? Unable to parse yaml to json is not enough to find out what is the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may need to know that helm essentially uses golang for template replacement, so the underlying implementation can refer to [go template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template?utm_source=godoc)

According [helm doc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/)

> Notice that we received a few empty lines in our YAML. Why? When the
> template engine runs, it removes the contents inside of {{ and }}, but
> it leaves the remaining whitespace exactly as is.
>
> YAML ascribes meaning to whitespace, so managing the whitespace
> becomes pretty important. Fortunately, Helm templates have a few tools
> to help.
>
> First, the curly brace syntax of template declarations can be modified
> with special characters to tell the template engine to chomp
> whitespace. {{- (with the dash and space added) indicates that
> whitespace should be chomped left, while -}} means whitespace to the
> right should be consumed. Be careful! Newlines are whitespace!
>
> Make sure there is a space between the - and the rest of your
> directive. {{- 3 }} means "trim left whitespace and print 3" while
> {{-3 }} means "print -3".

e.g.

values.yaml

````yaml
atest: test

templates/cm.yaml
```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  cfg1: |-
    {{ if eq $.Values.atest "test" }}
              ok1
    {{ end }}
  cfg2: |-


    {{- if eq $.Values.atest "test" }}

         ok2
    {{- end }}

  cfg3: |-
    ok

    {{- if eq $.Values.atest "test" -}}

       3      
    {{- end -}}

    xxxxx
````

cmd

```bash
helm template --debug test .
```

output

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  cfg1: |-
    
              ok1
    
  cfg2: |-

         ok2

  cfg3: |-
    ok3xxxxx
```

In detail:

- For `cfg1`, there is no `-` in `{{` or `}}`, after rendering, the carriage returns at the beginning and end of lines `{{ if }}` and `{{ end }}` are preserved, and the spaces before `ok1` are also preserved
- For `cfg2`, there is a `-` in `{{`, after rendering, the carriage returns at the end of lines `{{ if }}` and `{{ end }}` are retained, but the enter or spaces at the beginning are deleted
- For `cfg3`, there is `-` in `{{` and `}}`, after rendering, Therefore, after rendering, all enter and spaces before and after lines `{{ if }}` and `{{ end }}`, including those before `ok` `3`, all will be deleted

---

Last, For debug.

[helm Debugging Templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/debugging/)

`helm template --debug test .`

It's a great way to have the server render your templates, then return the resulting manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

In the [Go `text/template` language](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template), a hyphen `-` directly inside curly braces `{{ ... }}` causes whitespace *outside* the curly braces to be removed.  It's any whitespace (space, tab, carriage return, newline) on the same side as the hyphen.

```yaml
plain text: two words

has two spaces between words: two {{ printf "" }} words
has only one space: two {{- printf "" }} words
has only one space: two {{ printf "" -}} words
has no spaces: two {{- printf "" -}} words

#                      kept vv                vvvv dropped
has exactly two spaces:  two  {{ printf "" -}}    words
has exactly four spaces: two  {{- printf "" }}    words
#                   dropped ^^                ^^^^ kept

on one line since newlines are whitespace: two
{{- printf "" }} words
```

Other punctuation, including hyphens outside of curly braces, is always kept as-is.

As a rule of thumb it's often right to start template expressions at the first column and include a hyphen inside the open brace but not the closing brace.  That preserves a newline and indentation for the *following* line.

```yaml
metadata:
  labels:
{{- include "common.labels" . | indent 4 }}
    another: label
```

Running `helm template` on your chart will render it to YAML, and also try to parse it.  `helm template --debug` will print out the output even on a parse failure.  In this situation I tend to visually scan through the generated YAML to look for indentation errors or especially missing newlines (that is, a line like `value: foovolumeMounts:` that's two lines concatenated together).